# Are implementations to semiotics what proofs are to syntax, and models to semantics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, semantics, set-theory, semiotics, syntax

I see this term *implementation* and its family used here and there in writings on set theory. There are implementations of natural numbers, of ordered pairs, of functions, of "mathematics in general."

I feel like this is not the same as having a syntactically or semantically different set theory, one or another per implementation. It seems like Zermelo's ordinals could just as well be the ZFC ordinals as von Neumann's, and although there are the infamous "junk theorems" depending on one's implementation of the natural numbers, otherwise there seems like not enough of a semantic difference between the implementations to make a difference to whether one is "working in ZFC."

But those junk theorems *are* theorems, and it is either a permanently or historically open question, what implementation of the natural numbers is "most fitting."<sup>†</sup>

In a nearby universe, so to say, there is the question of functions. Von Neumann expressly axiomatized these in his implementation of ZFC, and even though attempts are made to this day to persuasively "reduce" functions to relations/ordered pairs, it remains an indelible fact (of the intellectual situation) that the axiom scheme of replacement axiomatizes functions in ZFC regardless. If we say with Frege that a functional representation of logic is "better" than the more antiquated subject-predicate representation, then we also seem to have functions in the form of the notation no matter when we get to have sets (or even numbers?) too.

And that last observation leads into my question: so are questions of implementations questions of logical *semiotics*? The fact that there is an SEP article on mathematical *style* specifically, suggests to me that there is such a thing as formal semiotics, so to say (alongside formal proofs as syntactic or formal models as semantic). That or "logical semiotics," maybe. And as the junk theorems show us, the semiotics of a system end up contributing decisively to the truth values of at least *some* statements.

This would also allow us to cash out Hilbert's philosophy of mathematics in terms of its similarity to, yet profound distinction from, logicism. The classical logicist can be seen as prizing the syntax over the semantics and the semiotics; the intuitionist and the realist favor the semantics, perhaps (or perhaps the intuitionist is as beholden to the semantics as the semiotics?); but Hilbert emphasized the formal semiotics above all else.

Are semiotics as such "parallel to" syntax and semantics? If this parallelism obtains, I would suspect that just as we have proof-theoretic ordinals vs. syntax and model-theoretic cardinals (initial worldly cardinals for a theory) vs. semantics, maybe there are, what, glyph-theoretic indexes, too? But I don't know that at all. I don't even know, to be honest, why the SEP article that goes over the Benacerraf identification problem says that there are infinitely many possible implementations of the natural numbers as sets. I've had a hard time coming up with even a few formats other than Zermelo's and von Neumann's (I sort of feel like Conway's left-set/right-set procedure can be framed as an implementation style, so I've had that in the back of my head this whole time, too), much less some unspecified "infinitely many" of these things (*which infinity*, by the way?).

*Is this what Peirce and Frege were getting at with their talk of multidimensional notation?*

<sup>†</sup><sub>Though the tendency has been to conclude that 2 is not reducible to {0, 1} *or* {{0}}, why not talk in the other direction and say that the term *2* turns out to be ambiguous, and hence there is not so much a thing as "the" number 2 as a variety of sets, any of which we "might" be referring to when we say "the number 2"? After all, both {0, {0}} and {{0}} exist in the ZFC universe no matter what: one is given with the pairset axiom, the other with the singleton axiom. Other than that, I will say, but of course per site policy not argue (that would be peddling a theory), that there is a reasonable method of justification in mathematics that at least filters out some rejoinders to Benacerraf's identification problem, while possibly allowing for a much stronger resolution. (Hint: assume that no previously given implementation of the natural numbers is individually sufficiently justified, and that the key to dealing with this is to try to design an implementation that ranges over all the others, so that their infinitesimal justification per implementation becomes a complete justification for the newly given format. This does depend on there being a possible transfinite induction over all the previous formats, if you will, or a class induction over all lesser formats; but other than that...)</sub>

Comment: Re your "semiotics parallel to syntax and semantics" metaphysical conjecture, if it's true, then what's the quotient notion after modulo all of the paralleled ones? Re your "there are infinitely many possible implementations of the natural numbers as sets" question, the standard oldest definition of the natural numbers is as equivalence classes of finite sets under bijection (Von Neumann's successor operation is unstratified so its usual ZFC definition of N cannot be proved exist in NFU), so 1:={∅}, 2:={{∅}}... for Zermelo's N, 1:={{∅}}, 2:={{{∅}}}... could be another equivalent N in Z style.

Comment: What are "implementation of natural numbers" in set theories? They are "structures" made of sets that behave like natural numbers, i.e. such that within set theory we can prove that they have all the known properties of natural numbers. As said, there are more than one; thus - see well-known [Benacerraf's paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Benacerraf) - it is doubtful that they are the "real" natural numbers (maybe only a proxy for them).

Comment: See also [Standard model](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232584/looking-for-a-source-for-intended-interpretation)

Comment: Regarding semiotics and mathematics (Saussure, Peirce, Frege) see Raymond Duval, [Understanding the Mathematical Way of Thinking. The Registers of Semiotic Representations (original edition 2011, Springer 2017)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Understanding_the_Mathematical_Way_of_Th/f70tDwAAQBAJ)